# Angularjs fake backend rest api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am developing **`AngularJS`** frontend **`API`**. But I need to use a rest API to try working behaviour of my application. So I should create backend services first. Is there any rest simulator like services to represent the backend. So I can separate the frontend and backend development.

Comment: You can point to dummy JSON files that later can be substituted by backend URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very smooth and easy way to make a development environment which acts completely the same as if there was a backend.

**This is what I have done:**

I created a dev module which is using `ngMockE2E` and wrapping my app module:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var appDev = angular.module('appDev', ['app', 'ngMockE2E']);

    appDev.run(runAppDev);

    runAppDev.$inject = ['$httpBackend', '$log', '$resource'];

    function runAppDev($httpBackend, $log, $resource) {
        $log.info('You are now in dev mode');

        $httpBackend.whenPOST('/test').respond(
           $resource('mock/test.json').get()
        );

        // Catch-all pass through for all other requests
        $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();
        $httpBackend.whenPOST(/.*/).passThrough();
        $httpBackend.whenDELETE(/.*/).passThrough();
        $httpBackend.whenPATCH(/.*/).passThrough();
    }
})();
```

Whenever I wanted to simulate the backend, I was initialising my app with:

```
<html ng-app="appDev">
    ....
</html>
```

As I said the advantage with this approach is, that you can implement your resource services (or http services) completely the same as in the real app with a backend. In the `appDev` module you just need to tell which API routes you wanted to have faked returning some mock json. In my case all other API routes are passed through to the backend.

This approach is by far the most convenient to work with since it only involves `angular-mocks` library and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a directory with the static json object you are expecting to be return and then launch a simpe server to serve those files

For instance, if you have a file p.json in directory DIR with the following content:
{"name":"henri","age":12}
launching the following command would publish that file at http://localhost:8000/p.json

> python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000

PS: this will work for your GET method, you would need something more sofisticated for your PUT and POST, but it's a start

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this [libray](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax) to emulate a API when developing the whole frontend.

Or you could use http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server to have fake XMLHttpRequest and a complete test suite

Or you can create static `json` files to query on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice working on both at the same time.

1. Write a REST route (+ tests)
2. Write a frontend page / directive / view /.. (+tests)
3. goto 1.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Atmo](https://github.com/Raathigesh/Atmo), A tool to mock Api's easily through a User interface.